# R ggplot2: odd behaviour of geom_quasirandom when colouring by a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a regular and happy user of `geom_quasirandom` from the `ggbeeswarm` package to make scatterplots where X is a factor. However, I think some recent updates or something I am doing is causing some odd behaviour when colouring dots. The same script was returning a good-looking figure not long ago.

A reproducible example:

```r
library(ggbeeswarm)

# this is correctly placing the dots:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=drat)) +
  geom_quasirandom()

# but when colouring dots by a factor, some of the dots get ligned up vertically,
# instead of being placed in a violin-like shape
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=drat, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_quasirandom()
# (notice particularly the third group of dots, see screenshot below)

# mysteriously, the width argument does not apply to these three dots ligned up vertically
# e.g. command below does not move these dots
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=drat, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_quasirandom(width=1)
```

Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you want `aes(..., group = 1)` to color your dots without affecting the grouping? But yes: `ggbeeswarm` was updated recently. And it was a major update with probably a lot of changes.

Comment: Ah, `group=1` solves it! Likely not the expected behaviour regardless (flagged it here: https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm/issues/83), but happy to accept as answer here if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To color your dots without affecting the positioning you have to explicitly set the `group` aes so that all points are treated as one group using `group=1` or by grouping by the x axis variable only (Would have expected that it does make a difference but looks like that doesn't matter):

```r
library(ggbeeswarm)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = drat, color = factor(cyl), group = 1)) +
  geom_quasirandom()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = drat, color = factor(cyl), group = factor(gear))) +
  geom_quasirandom()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Author of ggbeeswarm here- this behavior is a bug in v0.7.1 and should be fixed in v0.7.2, which I’ve just pushed to CRAN. Please let me know if this remains an issue!

Comment: And now stackoverflow is even richer with you as a member. Thanks for your amazing package, I’m using it regularly.